# jQuery var becomes undefined when it passes into .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am working on building a stupid simple jQuery image slider from scratch using no outline libraries or plugins. I am new to jQuery, but I am running into a bug that seems so stupid simple.

I define a var outside of a .click() function, and then when I try to call that var inside the .click() it is considered undefined. The weird thing is that I can call other vars. Any thoughts?

[Here is a fiddle of the slider](https://jsfiddle.net/TobinShields/xpvt214o/197792/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=1"></li>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=2"></li>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=3"></li>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=4"></li>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=5"></li>
        </ul>
        <span id="prev">&#8698;</span>
        <span id="next">&#8699;</span>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS

```
// Set Targets
var next = $('#next');
var prev = $('#prev');
var slides = $('.slider ul')

// Build the var to animate the length of the img
var imgWidth = "-=" + ($('.slider img').first().width());
// Find number of imgs
var numOfSlides = $('.slider ul li').length;
// Set Slidecount to 1
var slideCount = 1; 

// When next btn is clicked
next.click(function(){

    // Check vars in console
    console.log(numOfSlides + " Slides");
    console.log(slideCount); <-------------- This is being marked as undefined

    // Check to see if there are more slides
    if (slideCount < numOfSlides) {
        // Slide the images
        slides.animate({'margin-left': imgWidth}, 1000);
        // Add one to slide count
        slideCount++;
    // If there are no more images, reset margin to 0 and return to first
    } else {
        // Animate margin to 0
        slides.animate({'margin-left': 0}, 1000);
        // Resent counter to 1
        var slideCount = 1;
    }
});
```

When I click on the next arrow I see this printed in the console--it's strange because the numOfSlides shows as having a value, but it's the slideCount that does not.

[image: Screenshot of Console l]

**EDIT**: 
As I was building the fiddle I saw this error pop up saying that my var was out of scope? But why are other var about to work inside this function then?
[image: JS Fiddle Screenshot]

Comment: It's `undefined` because of the `var slideCount = 1` in the `else` branch and a mechanic called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your click function you are redefining the `slideCount` so this new one will be used inside the function and not the outer one.

The reason why the variable is `undefined` at your `console.log` is the [hoisting mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting): every declaration is brought to the beginning of the scope.

So to the compiler your code will look like

```
next.click(function(){
    var slideCount;  <----- hoisted here, value is undefined for now
    console.log(slideCount); <------- This is still undefined

    // Check to see if there are more slides
    if (slideCount < numOfSlides) {
        // ...
        // Add one to slide count
        slideCount++; <----- like undefined++
    } else {
        // ...
        // Resent counter to 1
        slideCount = 1; <---- initialized for the first time
    }
});
```

Comment: Gah! Thanks! That was a weird--dumb typo on my part. Thanks all! Good to know that has such an impact.

Answer (score 0):

Do not initialize `slideCount`  in else condition Just remove `var` before `slideCount`

> When you initialize same variable  again in local then scope of that
>   variable remove from current scope and re-initialize (which is limited
>   to the else scope It will always print undefined outside else)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // SLDIER

    // Set Targets
    var next = $('#next');
    var prev = $('#prev');
    var slides = $('.slider ul')

    // Build the var to animate the length of the img
    var imgWidth = "-=" + ($('.slider img').first().width());
    // Find number of imgs
    var numOfSlides = $('.slider ul li').length;
    // Set Slidecount to 1
    var slideCount = 1;

    // When next btn is clicked
    next.click(function(){

        // Check vars
        // What's strange is the numOfSlides are printing
        // But slideCount is considered undefined. Why?
        console.log(numOfSlides + " Slides");
        console.log(slideCount);

        // Check to see if there are more slides
        if (slideCount < numOfSlides) {
            // Slide the images
            slides.animate({'margin-left': imgWidth}, 1000);
            // Add one to slide count
            slideCount++;
        // If there are no more images, reset margin to 0 and return to first
        } else {
            // Animate margin to 0
            slides.animate({'margin-left': 0}, 1000);
            // Resent counter to 1
             slideCount = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.slider {
    margin: 20px 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 9999px;
}
.slider li {
    float: left;
}
.slider #next,
.slider #prev {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: white;
}
.slider #next {
    right: 2%;
}
.slider #prev {
    left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=1"></li>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=2"></li>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=3"></li>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=4"></li>
            <li><img class="slide img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500?text=5"></li>
        </ul>
        <span id="prev">&#8698;</span>
        <span id="next">&#8699;</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are scoping `slideCount` to the click handler by re-setting it using the `var` keyword in here:

```
else {
        // Animate margin to 0
        slides.animate({'margin-left': 0}, 1000);
        // Resent counter to 1
        var slideCount = 1; // <-- here
    }
```

If you remove this it works, since the browser now "knows" that you are referring to the same variable, regardless of scope here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hzu05xL4/

It is undefined because it is only created later down the road in that scope. The other variables are fine, since they aren't re-created in that scope

Comment: But why is it `undefined` ?

Comment: It is undefined because it is only created later down the road in that scope

Answer (score 0):

Your var is `undefined` because:

```
var a = 1; //-> defined at the top of global code
a = 2;
console.log(a); //2 

(function(){
console.log(a);//undefined 
var a = 3;  // -> at a top of function code but undefined till now  
})();
```

If you remove `var`, then you could use previous var definition. Is undefined because declarations are processed before any code is executed ,also var declaration is scoped (in this case, second declaration lives only inside the function ).  `= 3` is processed later. Also var declaration is scoped